# Excel macro to split text in a cell to multiple rows fixed number of characters

Tags: excel, vba, string, cell, rows

I have a single cell with

```
abcd efg hi jklm    efghijk          abcdedfg ijkl
```

I need to split the text every 20 characters into a new row, so I end up with

```
Row2 - abcd efg hi jklm
Row3 - efghijk
Row4 - abcdedfg ijkl
```

Image:

[image: Better data]

I have added a better description of what I need to do with the data, the code offered works really well and splits the data every 20 chars into new rows, I need to further split the data, if someone could please help me I would appreciate it.

Comment: What's your issue? What have you tried? Do result rows contain whitespaces?

Comment: Hi in a single cell I have 00A      00                Channel Island Glass                                 00B      00                Channel Island Bulk                                  00C      00                Channel Island Polys I need a macro to put 00a   00   channel island glass in a2, 00b  00     Channel island bulk in a3, etc the text string needs to split every 80 characters. The text string is longer so need to create as many rows as needed. Thanks

Comment: This isn't a description of issue, you just listed your requirements

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try:

```
Sub SplitStringFixed()
    Dim s As String, i As Long
    s = [A1]
    For i = 1 To (Len(s) / 20) + 1
        Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = Mid(s, 1 + (i - 1) * 20, 20)
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

Without `VBA` you could just put:

```
=MID($A$1,20*(ROWS($1:1)-1)+1,20)
```

and copy downward.

**EDIT#1:**

Because of the presence of space characters it is difficult to see the details of the splitting.  Here is the map:

[image]

Comment: This works as requested, If allowed I would like to ask if you could also add the code to allow at within each 20 characters that this looks at that the chars 1-3 go into column A, 4-10 go into column B and 11-20 go into column C, then repeat for the next 20 characters etc that would then be perfect for me really appreciate your help

Comment: Yep the formula equally works to split every 20 characters thankyou

Comment: My apologies, I didnt give the best data, I am quickly learning to improve, hopefully this makes it clearer to understand what I am trying to do.

Comment: @AndyMitchell If you need to provide more information *edit the question*, don't edit the Answer - that's is an ***Answer***.